# Element rotating off-center

Tags: css, css-transforms

I want to rotate the [refresh icon from mdi](https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/icon/refresh/) with `transform rotate`. Due to the arrow head, the graphic unfortunately does not have its center at the center of the circle which makes the rotation animation a bit wobbly.

Is there any way to fix this with CSS?

If the icon is static, I can fix it by adding a little offset with `margin` or `transform translate`. But both are relative to the coordinate system of the page, so this does not fix the wobbling when the graphic is being animated as the offset does not rotate with the graphic.

Is there any directive that allows me to move the graphic relative to its own coordinate system so that the offset rotates with the graphic?

Comment: Which element are you adding the animation to? That svg you linked has the correct alignment to allow for correct rotation.

Comment: First off, some code would be helpful. If you are working in SVG you can use `transform-box: fill-box;` to move the coordinate system to the bounds of the fill of the element. You can use `transform-origin` anywhere to define the origin point of the transform, this also works on non-SVG elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

Put a `div` as a container around the icon element. Use `padding` to align the icon within the container so that the center of the circle is the center of the container. Then rotate the container.

Answer (score 1):

The `transform-origin` values don't have to be "center", "left" or whatever words, but can also be defined in percentage or pixel values, which allows any offset you need. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Awesome! I did not know that pixel values are possible. Thanks a bunch, that could be the solution.